# How do I find all occurences of a given property in a list of objects where the property is in depth n?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**The Issue:** Given a list of objects(model) and a path(eg: "organization.LongName") I wish to find all values that match this path and push them to an array.

This is a plnkr with this issue : [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/frIhT09ixJkFhGp1ZGo7?p=preview)

And an illustration showing an example object and the values I am interested in

[image]

*EDIT: Looking at these answers it would appear that I have been unclear in my explanation. The point here is that

1. *the path is a variable and passed as a string. like : "x.y.z...n"*
2. *I dont know its depths in advance and as such I need to be able to find the property regardless of the depth of the property.*

Comment: then your best option is to use JSONPath as explained in one of the answers and wrap it within a function that takes the string path and return the desired attributes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my answer is a bit off the wall, and also introduces a library dependency, but if you want something a bit more flexible rather than straight-up loops and code, you may want to consider [JSONPath](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/) which allows you to interact with JavaScript objects/arrays as you would XPath, only with a little [different syntax](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/ExprSyntax).

Given the model in your plnkr example, the following will give you the list you desire:

```
jsonPath(model,'$..organization..LongName');

// $ = the root element
// .. = descend until whatever comes next (either organization or LongName)
// organization|LongName = the object you're looking for
```

The result snippet is:

```
["Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern browsers you can use the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var obj = {
  id: 0,
  organization:[
  {id:0, LongName:"group A"},
  {id:1, LongName:"group B"}
  ],
  number: 123,
  LongName: "John World"
};

var groupLabels = obj.organization.map(function(e){
    return e.LongName;
});

console.log(groupLabels);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVACV/)

If your stuck somewhere that insists on using outdated browsers you can shim the `map()` function in using the code provided in the compatibility section within the above MDN link.

Answer (score 0):

consider this solution

```
function getOccurences(jsonObject, path) {
  path = '$..' + path.replace('.','..');
  return jsonPath(jsonObject, path);
}
```

you can call it this way:

```
getOccurences(someJsonData, 'organization.LongName')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this this works perfect.

```
function getValuesFromArray(obj, property)
{
    // obj = your object in which you want to find your property
    // property == your property which you want to find
    for(var index=0; index<obj.length; index++)
    {
        if(obj[index] instanceof Object)
            getValuesFromObject(obj[index], property);
        else if(obj[value] instanceof Object)
            getValuesFromObject(obj[value], property);
    }
}

function getValuesFromObject(obj, property)
{
    // obj = your object in which you want to find your property
    // property == your property which you want to find
    for(value in obj)
    {
        if(value == property)
            myArray.push(obj[property]);
        else if(obj[value] instanceof Array)
            getValuesFromArray(obj[value], property);
        else if(obj[value] instanceof Object)
            getValuesFromObject(obj[value], property);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? at no point are you touching property which at this point could be something along the lines of "Organization.Department.LongName.Name" meaning you would have to traverse the entire object

Comment: yes I am sure you just need to declare globel array named 'myArray' with this two functions and you are able to fetch any property from any no of recursion.